# PDF Compression and editing techniques

Tags: pdf, compression

I am not sure this question belongs on a programming forum but then again not sure where it would.

I currently open any PDF documents in Adobe Acrobat 9 Pro when reading or editing files. Many times, I want to make a change to the text in those files and will simply use the Tools->Advanced Editing->Touch Up Text Tool to do so.

No issues with the actual text changes but when I go back to save the file, the file size increases drastically. Even after running Advanced->PDF Optimizer and Document->Reduce File Size, the size is still much larger than the previous file, in many cases even if I am reducing the amount of text on that page.

It is quite frustrating. I am sure entire books have been written about proper PDF compression but take one text only document I have for example: file size is 110KB for a 12 page document. We just migrated to Google Apps and an entire 72 page PDF was under 600 KB.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Belongs on superuser.com imho; voting to move this question over there...

Answer (score 0):

Save as... your document after some changes.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the font data is being embedded into the PDF when you edit it. Run Acrobat's Space Audit on the original and modified PDF to determine what is taking up the extra space in the modified PDF.